# Why is Eclipselink changing the order of joins incorrectly?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a query like this in JPQL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Receipt AS receipt
   JOIN Invoice AS invoice
ON receipt.invoiceID = invoice.id
   LEFT JOIN Payment AS payment
ON receipt.paymentID = payment.id
   LEFT JOIN CreditNote AS creditNote
ON receipt.crmID = creditNote.id
   LEFT JOIN Profile AS profile
ON invoice.accountID = profile.accountID
WHERE ...
```

However when I run it with EclipseLink I get this native query which is invalid

```
SELECT ...
FROM   receipts t0
   LEFT OUTER JOIN payments t2
                ON ( t0.payment_id = t2.id )
   LEFT OUTER JOIN credit_notes t3
                ON ( t0.crm_id = t3.id )
   LEFT OUTER JOIN profiles t4
                ON ( t1.account_id = t4.account_id ),
   invoices t1
WHERE ...
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to change the `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` for all of the joins and then my ordering was respected.

I suspect the underlying issue is a bug in EclipseLink.